# Cannot include "SDL2_ttf" or "SDL2_image"

Tags: c++, macos, sdl-2

When i run code it had an error:

```
src/snake/Screen.hpp:7:10: fatal error: 'SDL_ttf.h' file not found
   #include "SDL_ttf.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~
   1 error generated.
   make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I included sdl2 library in my project and i only have problems with sdl2_image and sdl2_ttf.

This is my makefile:

```
SRC_DIR = src/snake
BUILD_DIR = build/debug
CC = g++
SRC_FILES = $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)
OBJ_NAME = play
INCLUDE_PATHS = -Iinclude
LIBRARY_PATHS = -Llib
COMPILER_FLAGS = -std=c++11 -Wall -O0 -g
LINKER_FLAGS = -lsdl2 -lsdl2_image -lsdl2_ttf

all:
    $(CC) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) $(LINKER_FLAGS) $(INCLUDE_PATHS) $(LIBRARY_PATHS) $(SRC_FILES) -o $(BUILD_DIR)/$(OBJ_NAME)
```

Comment: You know they are plugins and need to be downloaded separately?

Comment: I downloaded them through homebrew and set up them into my project in Vscode

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<SDL_ttf.h>` if you have installed the library on your machine, see [What is the difference between #include < > and #include " "?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename)

Another case is that you mistyped (lowercased) all the libraries name on `LINKER_FLAGS`, thus the compiler did not found any of the library you were specifying, try `LINKER_FLAGS = -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_ttf`.